# mySQL Returning the top 5 of each category

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to be able to return 5 menuitem per menu. I've tried this several script but had no luck. here are the tables

```
menus
-------
menuid int()
profileName varchar(35)

menuitems
-----------
itemid int()
name varchar(40)
```

Here what I have now. I'm getting the error message with the script below. Error: Subquery returns more then 1 row.

```
SELECT m.profilename, name
FROM menus m 
WHERE (SELECT name
        from menuitems s
        where m.menuid = s.menuid
        limit 5)
```

Any suggestion is great appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use side effecting variables for this

```
SELECT profilename, name
FROM
(
    SELECT m.profilename, s.name,
        @r:=case when @g=m.profilename then @r+1 else 1 end r,
        @g:=m.profilename
    FROM (select @g:=null,@r:=0) n
    cross join menus m 
    left join menuitems s on m.menuid = s.menuid
) X
WHERE r <= 5
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been stuck on this for days.

Comment: WOW... selection of inline variables in a query... I've never seen that before... Strange, but cool.

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT TOP 5 m.profilename, s.name
FROM menus m INNER JOIN menuitems s ON m.menuID = s.menuid
```

Comment: Are you assuming that he has `menuid` in `menuitems` table?

Comment: mysql does not support "TOP N".