# MySQL fetch X columns for each category_id

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know if this is possible in mysql via ONE query .

assuming I have a table "products" that has "id","category_id","product_name","price"

Case 1 : I want to fetch 5 products from each category where price is more than 100$

Case 2: I want to fetch

1-"3 products from category 1"

2- "5 products from category 2"

3- "3 products from category 2 where the price is more than 100 and is not fetched in point 2 above"

each case in ONE query , is that possible ?

PS : The table has about 100K rows ...

Comment: You can, but before solution is presented I'd just warn you that this is extremely ineffective way of retrieving data.

Comment: HI Michael , the idea is that i have a page with 50 queries which is very heavy on a loaded server (1000 hits/second !) but all those queries read form the same table , so i wish i could fetch the 200 rows i need then separate them to arrays and using these arrays to print out the data to the output .

Comment: @Michael J.V. Not flaming you or nothing, but could you support your comment? I'm curious, and would like to know!  Would it just be because it takes excess cycles?

Comment: How many categories are there?

Comment: ranging from 4 to 64 and might be more someday if the owner of the site decided to add some ...

Comment: @Ronan - you should probably cache your results with a mechanism such as Memcache. I doubt that your data changes so frequently that you need the latest copy from the database. @Chris - It's extremely inefficient in terms of how long it takes you to add another rule to the query you construct. From performance point of view - it is always faster to have two simple queries (using indexes preferably) than one that self-joins a table to itself (tho there are exceptions). In a case of highly visited website - I think Memcache would make your life easier and reduce DB hits.

Comment: @ Michael , caching technique exists for sure ! but the problem is we need to turn off the cache for those queries for an hour a day where data should be life (up to the second) , tables are optimized/indexed to the max !

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the FYI, very clear to me now why it is in-efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this method : it is VERY fast and gave me exactly what i wanted :

```
SELECT  l.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  category,
                COALESCE(
                (
                SELECT  id
                FROM    writings li
                WHERE   li.category= dlo.category 
                ORDER BY
                        li.category, li.id
                LIMIT 15, 1
                ), CAST(0xFFFFFFFF AS DECIMAL)) AS mid
        FROM    (
                SELECT  id as category
                FROM    cats dl 
                ) dlo
        ) lo, writings l
WHERE   l.category>= lo.category
        AND l.category<= lo.category
        AND l.id <= lo.mid
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could do this using nested select statements.

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/subqueries.html

Although, I'm not sure how you would utilize them as seperate select statements after you've gotten your query.  I mean, they will all be one record set.

Comment: Hi Chris , i already gone through that page , didnt find what i am looking for .

Comment: There are tones of pages on google that show you how to do a nested select statement though... I just picked one.

Comment: i wish i could do that without nesting otherwise it defers nothing from having many queries and reading the table many times

Comment: Yes I agree, I just noticed in your other comment how active this is.

Answer (score 0):

Case 2 I think I've got...

```
  (
  select * from products where category_id = 1 limit 3
  )
union 
  ( 
  select * from products where category_id = 2 limit 5
  )
union (
  select * from products where category_id = 2 and price > 100 limit 3
)
```

Note that `union` will eliminate duplicates, `union all` will allow duplicates (and is therefor faster).

Have you seen?
[mySQL Returning the top 5 of each category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729406/mysql-returning-the-top-5-of-each-category)

That looks like what you're asking...

Comment: Thanks Johan , but whats the use in it if you read the same table with every `select` statement ? is it possible with one select statement (i don't want to read the table again and again it's too expensinve)