# SQL selecting of the first X rows of a specific table column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, row

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mySQL Returning the top 5 of each category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729406/mysql-returning-the-top-5-of-each-category)

What SQL query can help me get the first 2 rows of each Course column:

```
ID Course Action
1  1      read
2  1      read
3  1      edit
4  2      edit
5  2      write
6  2      read
7  3      read
8  3      post
```

I would like to get records: 1,2,4,5,7,8