# how to get top 5 for each category

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql.
I have one table called flow_data
There is two attributes category and views.
category is int type and views is int type.
category has 0-4(for example num 0 is video and num 1 is pics) and numbers of view is based on how many times users click.
I want to query data that top5 views for each category.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, cat, title, file, type, tags
FROM flow_data 
ORDER BY views 
LIMIT 5
```

It only returns top5 views not based on each category.

Any thought? Thank you advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is rank query in oracle and sql server you may search for rank equivalent in mysql. You may see [here](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/mysql/2007/04/12/emulating-analytic-aka-ranking-functions-with-mysql.html). You may also see [this](http://frishit.com/2010/07/mysql-selecting-top-n-per-group/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729406/mysql-returning-the-top-5-of-each-category) also