# Db2 - Returning the top 5 of each category

Tags: sql, db2, greatest-n-per-group

I want to be able to return 5 menuitem per menu. 
Here are the tables

```
menus
-------
menuid int()
profileName varchar(35)

menuitems
-----------
itemid int()
name varchar(40)
menuid int()
```

I do see a solution for MySQL in this thread - [mySQL Returning the top 5 of each category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729406/mysql-returning-the-top-5-of-each-category), looking for similar solution for DB2. 
Any suggestion is great appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

something like:

```
select ...
from (
    select ..., row_number() over ( partition by m.menuid
                                    order by ? ) as rn 
    from menus m
    join menuitems mi
        m.menuid = mi.menuid
)
where rn <= 5;
```

Troels Arvin has a comparision of different DBMS at:

```
http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/
```

Amongst other things quota queries (such as the one you are asking) are discussed

Comment: @JunJingZhang your question is not clear about how you want to determine which are the "top 5" in each menu. generally an id column is a generated surrogate key, rather than a natural key. A natural key would be a column that represents a real world attribute of what the row represents or how it is used. In this case, a sequence number within the menu would be an example. That is one example of what you might use where the "?" is above.