# DB2 - How to select only the first N rows for each unique value of a column

Tags: select, db2

In DB2, how do we select first 'N' rows for each unique value of a column. For example, given a table like this:

```
Number Flower
21     Rose
22     Lily
21     Tulip
21     Orchid
22     Hibiscus
22     Carnation
```

Select first 2 flowers for each number. I should be able to get the result as:

```
21 Rose
21 Tulip
22 Lily
22 Hibiscus
```

Comment: Relational tables do not have any intrinsic order of rows, so in the absence of explicit ordering there is no "first N rows". In your example it is impossible to determine how the rows with the same `Number` value are ordered.

Comment: Classic [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem, like [this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802759/db2-returning-the-top-5-of-each-category).  You just haven't figured out what "top" means yet.