# sql db2 select most recent entry of each employee and their previous entry

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with entries for each employee. Every time they change jobs a new entry is created. This is done by date. So, employee, start date, job, end date. I am looking for each employees most recent job and their previous job. I can get the max or most recent job ,but getting the previous job is the problem i am having.

column headers: Employee, Start date, Job, End date

Below is what i have tried:

```
with E as
(select
  rownum = row_number() over (partition by employee order by startdate)
,employee
,startdate
,job
,enddate
from table )
Select * 
from E
where e.rownum >1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Db2 - Returning the top 5 of each category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802759/db2-returning-the-top-5-of-each-category)

Comment: `rownum = row_number()` is invalid SQL. You can't assign a variable in a SQL statement like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with E as
(select
  rownum = row_number() over (partition by employee order by startdate desc)
,employee
,startdate
,job
,enddate
from table )
Select 
employee
,startdate
,job
,enddate
,case when  rownum =  1 then 'recent' else 'previous' End as Job_stat
from E
where e.rownum <=2
```

Comment: just as a followup question would there be a way to show just the employees who have a job change. not all employees have a job change

Comment: Sorry i didnt get that. May be a new question with sample data and expected output