# Joining tables by using the maximum value of one of the tables

Tags: sql, db2

I'm having difficulty joining two tables on the ID column and the maximum value of EVNT_SEQ. For example, I have a table full of users and I want to see their most recent action. The evnt_tbl adds a row for each user event. I want to write a query that returns all the users and their most recent event (the MAX of EVNT_SEQ).

Database Version: IBM DB2 9.7.8

**person_tbl**

```
ID    NAME
1     Ben
2     Joe
3     Jane
4     Albert
5     Paul
```

**evnt_tbl**

```
ID    EVNT_SEQ    EVNT_NM
1     1           NULL
1     2           max
2     1           NULL
2     2           NULL
2     3           max
3     1           max
4     1           NULL
4     2           max
5     1           NULL
5     2           max
```

**desired query results**

```
ID    NAME     EVNT_SEQ    EVNT_NM
1     Ben      2           max
2     Joe      3           max
3     Jane     1           max
4     Albert   2           max
5     Paul     2           max
```

I thought I could write something like the following but I get an error:

```
SELECT person.ID, person.NAME, evnt.EVNT_SEQ, evnt.EVNT_NM
FROM person_tbl person
LEFT JOIN evnt_tbl evnt ON person_tbl.ID = evnt.ID
    AND evnt.EVNT_SEQ = (SELECT MAX(EVNT_SEQ) 
                             FROM event_tbl evnt2 
                             WHERE evnt.ID = evnt2.ID)
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: It looks like you already have a field that tells you which row is the max. Why do you need to recalculate it in a query?

Comment: @Rabbit Sorry that was misleading. That was just for demonstration purposes. In the actual table, the events have different names.

Comment: Then you can use the ROW_NUMBER() function and partition on ID and order by the event sequence in descending order and return only those where the row number is equal to 1.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802759/db2-returning-the-top-5-of-each-category) of standard [tag:greatest-n-per-group] questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a derived table to get the max values for each id in the event table. Then join the result to the person table.

```
select t.id, p.name, t.maxevseqm, t.maxevnum
from (SELECT ID, max(EVNT_SEQ) as maxevseq, max(EVNT_NM) as maxevnum
      FROM event_tbl
      group by id) t
join person_tbl on p.id = t.id
```

Comment: Judging by the latest comment, EVNT_NM isn't guaranteed to be max.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  p.id, p.name, e.EVNT_SEQ, e.EVNT_NM
from 
  person_tbl p
inner join
  evnt_tbl e
on 
  p.id = e.id and e.EVNT_SEQ =
  (
  select MAX(EVNT_SEQ)
  from evnt_tbl xe
  where xe.id = p.id
  )
```

Tested with [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51e11/3)